# javascript get value of <textarea> issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to store json data in a textarea temporally then i can use it later.
in text.js got bellow function:

```
function getList(pageNo, pageLimit, id, queryData){
    var $container = $('#js-skp-table'), 
        $pageContainer =  $('#js-skp-pager'),
        $pageNum = $('#js-skp-num'),
        $tmpl = $('#js-skp-item');
    $.ajax({
        url     : '/test/url/'+ id,
        data    : $.extend({}, queryData, {page: pageNo+1, limit: pageLimit}),
        type    : 'GET',
        cache   :false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            var items = [];
            if(data.data && data.data.length > 0){
                $.each(data.data, function(index){
                    items.push( $tmpl.tmpl(data.data[index])[0]);
                });
                var tempStr = JSON.stringify(searchDataArr);
                tempStr=tempStr.replace(/\"/g,"'");         
                $('#myTextarea').text(tempStr); 
                console.log('testarea:'+$('#myTextarea').val()); // got output 
                $container.empty().append(items);
                $pageNum.text(data.data.length);
                $pageContainer.empty().pagination(data.total, {
                    items_per_page      : pageLimit,
                    current_page        : pageNo,
                    callback            : function(page, component){
                        window.location.hash = '#page=' + page;
                        getList(page, pageLimit, id, queryData);
                    }
                });
            }
        },

    });
}
```

in text.html

```
getList(0, 10, id, queryData);
console.log('testarea:'+$('#myTextarea').val()); // output nothing.
```

updated to

```
getList(0,50,seckill_id).complete(function() {
console.log('testarea:'+$('#myTextarea').val());
});
```

now, my question is: how come first console.log got output value, but second not?
then, new error come out:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'complete' of undefined

Comment: It does not work because it is ASYNCHRONOUS. What you did was call the pizza company and as soon as you hung up the phone you are trying to eat the pizza you just ordered. You can not do it, you need to wait for it to be delivered. Hence why there is a callback.

Comment: so how i know the function executed? "$container.empty().append(items);",on test.html, showed the html content already. how to solve this problem?